# How do i provide dynamic library (.so) in ./configure command?

Tags: configuration, automake

How do i provide dynamic library (.so) in  ./configure command?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you are asking "How do I tell configure the location of a dynamic library?"  Typically, you specify the locations of libraries by setting LDFLAGS.  For example:

```
$ ./configure LDFLAGS=-L/path/to/lib
```